# mysql workbench error 1262. how can I imort big size data

Tags: mysql

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/bok_indicators.csv'
INTO TABLE findb.bok_indicators
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

> 12:44:36  LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/bok_indicators.csv' INTO TABLE findb.bok_indicators FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   Error Code: 1262. Row 91 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns    0.031 sec

That is the error message.  I want to import a csv file.  It has over 2,000 rows
How can I do that?

Comment: This sounds like there was some bad data on row 91.  Can include the first 2 rows and the 91st row, of your CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

This error was fixed for me by locating and deleting (or replacing) backslashes and/or commas in the data. Open in text editor (e.g., Notepad++) and find and replace those characters and see if that was the issue.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you for being diligent about putting the solution as an answer. Please feel free to accept your own answer when the system allows.